# MuPAD has Different output from regular m file

Tags: matlab, mupad

I'm going to plot a function in MuPAD tool in Matlab, it seems it's not correct.

my function in (MuPAD) is:

```
P = exp(-10)*10^n/n!
plot(P, n=0:24);
```

and in a regular m-file is:

```
n=0:24;
P = exp(-10).*(10.^n)/factorial(n);
plot(n,P);
```

Its result is diagonal line which is not true. However, the same function in regular m file script is plotted very well. Any idea?

Comment: Sure you are using the exact code? I'd rather expected to define `n` before actually calculating `P` (the way you do it should get you an undefined error), or by defining P as a anonymous function (`P = @(n) ....`) Maybe you run the script in Matlab before so that n was defined before actually calling/running it again, thus it worked in matlanb...

Comment: I assume you did not even try your code before in MATLAB... `n!` is not valid in MATLAB to calculate the factorial: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/factorial.html

Comment: @tim, n! is valid in MuPAD not in m-files

Comment: Alright I was assuming the identical code was used in the m-script. Then please also post the m-file which is plotted alright in MATLAB :-)

Comment: @tim, m-file version code is included